# Segmentation fault on library call

Tags: c++, segmentation-fault, chipmunk

I'm using a physics library called Chipmunk for a game that I'm writing.

In my `initialize` function I initialize the global variable `cpSpace space`. Then in update I  call `cpSpaceStep(space, timestep)`. The prototype for this function is `void cpSpaceStep(cpSpace *space, cpFloat dt);`. I'm getting a  segfault on this function call. I've marked those two function calls in the code below.

The full code is below:

```
#include "../include/SDL/SDL_image.h"
#include "../include/SDL/SDL.h"
#include "../include/Player.h"
#include "../include/Timer.h"
#include "../include/Block.h"
#include "../include/ImageLoader.h"
#include "../include/chipmunk/chipmunk.h"
#include <string>

//Screen attributes
const int SCREEN_WIDTH = 640;
const int SCREEN_HEIGHT = 480;
const int SCREEN_BPP = 32;

//The frame rate
const int FRAMES_PER_SECOND = 60;

SDL_Event event;
SDL_Surface *screen = NULL;
SDL_Surface *player_img = NULL, *block_img = NULL;
Player *player;
Timer fps;
cpSpace *space;

bool quit = false;

void initialize();
void update();

int main( int argc, char* argv[] )
{
    initialize();
    update();

    return 1;
}

void initialize()
{
    //Initialize all SDL subsystems
    if( SDL_Init( SDL_INIT_EVERYTHING ) == -1 )
    {

    }

    //Set up the screen
    screen = SDL_SetVideoMode( SCREEN_WIDTH, SCREEN_HEIGHT, SCREEN_BPP, SDL_SWSURFACE );

    //If there was an error in setting up the screen
    if( screen == NULL )
    {

    }

    //Set the window caption
    SDL_WM_SetCaption( "Move the Dot", NULL );

    cpVect gravity = cpv(0, 100);

//******************cpSpacenew()*****************       
//This is where space is init'ed
    space = cpSpaceNew();
//***********************************************


}

void update()
{
    //While the user hasn't quit
    while( quit == false )
    {
        //Start the frame timer
        fps.start();

        while( SDL_PollEvent( &event ) )
        {
            //Handle events for the dot
            player->handle_input( &event );

            //If the user has Xed out the window
            if( event.type == SDL_QUIT )
            {
                //Quit the program
                quit = true;
            }
        }

        player->update();

        cpFloat timeStep = 1.0/FRAMES_PER_SECOND; 

  //************************Segfault**********************************************
        cpSpaceStep(space, timeStep);
  //******************************************************************************

        //Cap the frame rate
        if( fps.get_ticks() < 1000 / FRAMES_PER_SECOND )
        {
            SDL_Delay( ( 1000 / FRAMES_PER_SECOND ) - fps.get_ticks() );
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I can post gdb output if needed.

Comment: The solution should be obvious from the `gdb` output.

Comment: what does `cpSpaceNew()` return? A pointer or a reference?

Answer (score 2):

Where's your `cpInitChipmunk()` call? Without that, it's likely that `cpSpaceNew()` may well return NULL (or junk).

Easy enough to check. Immediately after the call to `cpSpaceNew()`, insert a:

```
printf ("%p\n", space);
```

(or something equivalent, to see what the value is.

You may also want to do that immediatley before trying to use it as well, just in case something corrupts it.

Comment: I added a couple printf's where you suggested, and added the cpInitChipmunk(). The output I got from the printf's was two identical memory addresses. So it's initialized properly and not corrupted.

Comment: Did you check the values _before_ you added the init call (and is it still crashing)? Debugging 101 mandates that you only change _one_ thing at a time. And, what _was_ the pointer value that was printed?

Comment: I took out the init call and ran the code. Got 015D184 for the pointer. Added init, recompiled, got 01711840. It's still crashing.

Comment: Which version of Chipmunk is it? cpSpaceNew should have an iterations argument according to my doco. And you don't seem to be connecting the gravity vector to the space.

Comment: I'm using chipmunk 6.0.3 (free version). I call cpSpaceSetGravity(space, gravity) later, but I deleted that since it was after the segfault.

Comment: Ah, that explains it. However, if the pointers are identical between create and use, you'll need to look into the content of the cpSpace structure to see if something like the cpbody pointer has been corrupted.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/8569/discussion-between-bryan-glazer-and-paxdiablo)

Answer (score 0):

Could be because `space` is NULL when you call `cpSpaceStep()`. And in `cpSpaceStep()` function, an attempt is done to dereference the pointer which is `NULL`. Check whether `space` is properly initialized in `initialize()`.

Comment: See the comments in my discussion with paxdiablo. It's not a null ptr.