# Segmentation fault on ffi call from Pharo Smalltalk

Tags: c++, segmentation-fault, smalltalk, pharo, chipmunk

I'm using a physics library called Chipmunk(version 7.0.1) for a game engine in Pharo Smalltalk(version 6). 
I initialize a Space with a call to function "cpSpaceNew()" and i´m correctly getting the pointer to cpSpace structure. Then i want to set the gravity to the space using a call to function "cpSpaceSetGravity(space, gravity)" and i get a Segmentation Fault.
I found a similar question : [Segmentation fault on library call](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9578248/segmentation-fault-on-library-call)
but it is old question and did not find solution there.

**EDIT:**

Getting cpSpace pointer with:

```
^ self ffiCall: #( cpSpace* cpSpaceNew(void) )
```

**"ffical:"** is native call from Smalltalk.

Trying to set the gravity with:

```
^ (self ffiCalloutIn: thisContext sender)
    convention: self ffiCallingConvention;
    options: #( optIndirectCall );
    function: #(void cpSpaceSetGravity (self , cpVect aVector)) module: self ffiLibraryName
```

This way of function call is because it is an "inline function" and it is not load in Library.

Comment: Without code this is anyone's guess. Check the documentation to make sure you're calling it correctly. Check your debugger.

Comment: Updated with some info, hope can help.

Comment: What do you mean by "inline function"? Either the library provides the function or it doesn't, regardless of how the declaration may look in code. You're explicitly telling the FFI interface that you want the function looked up in `self ffiLibrary`. If the function is not being provided by the library, what do you expect to happen? It's not magic... ;)

Comment: Inline function is a function with the kwyword "inline" , for more info : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inline_function. As i said "Inline" functions are not exported by the library, so "Chipmunk" defines a MACRO that exports an alias as a pointer to the function . #ffiCall: does not expect a pointer, so i must do a "indirect call"  to resolve symbol to function pointer and call the function.

Answer (score 1):

Which gcc version are you using?  I recommend using older or maybe ancient one.

Excerpt from Pharo mailing list:

> My understanding is that gcc 4.8(.4) is the default version in trusty,
>   so if anyone else wants to build the VM with the same compiler,
>   they'll need gcc 4.8.
>
> At the moment it is needed because a few people have found that the VM
>   doesn't work properly if compiled with gcc 5.4